# Microk8s Cert-Manager Issuer Apply Error : service "certmgr-cert-manager-webhook" not found

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, cert-manager, microk8s

I am having an error when I need to apply issuer.

`kubectl apply -f issuer-lets-encrypt-staging.yaml`

```
Error from server (InternalError): error when creating "issuer-lets-encrypt-staging.yaml": 
Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "webhook.cert-manager.io": 
failed to call webhook: 
Post "https://certmgr-cert-manager-webhook.cert-manager.svc:443/mutate?timeout=10s": 
service "certmgr-cert-manager-webhook" not found
```

My issuer

```
# issuer-lets-encrypt-staging.yaml
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Issuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-staging
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: <email-address> # ❗ Replace this with your email address
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-staging
    solvers:
    - http01:
        ingress:
          name: web-ingress
```

referenced from : https://cert-manager.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started-with-cert-manager-on-google-kubernetes-engine-using-lets-encrypt-for-ingress-ssl/

List of my cert-manager resources

```
kubectl -n cert-manager get all                  
NAME                                           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/cert-manager-cainjector-64d74f9c8f-szj8d   1/1     Running   0          20m
pod/cert-manager-b4b465456-lnjtw               1/1     Running   0          20m
pod/cert-manager-webhook-66fff58cdf-dtdcv      1/1     Running   0          20m

NAME                           TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
service/cert-manager           ClusterIP   10.152.183.213   <none>        9402/TCP   20m
service/cert-manager-webhook   ClusterIP   10.152.183.44    <none>        443/TCP    20m

NAME                                      READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/cert-manager-cainjector   1/1     1            1           20m
deployment.apps/cert-manager              1/1     1            1           20m
deployment.apps/cert-manager-webhook      1/1     1            1           20m

NAME                                                 DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/cert-manager-cainjector-64d74f9c8f   1         1         1       20m
replicaset.apps/cert-manager-b4b465456               1         1         1       20m
replicaset.apps/cert-manager-webhook-66fff58cdf      1         1         1       20m
```

I coundn't solve this problem for a month.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Requirements:** your microk8s cluster MUST be accessible from the Internet on port 80 and 443 via domains you need to get certificates for. If you're running microk8s on your home computer it means that you have to set up port forwarding on your home router and domains must resolve to its external IP address.

Install this addon with:

```
microk8s enable cert-manager
```

**Create a ClusterIssuer:**

A ClusterIssuer resource is used to configure an account with Let’s Encrypt. All you need is an email address (make sure to use a valid email address).

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-staging
spec:
  acme:
#change to your email
    email: youremail@gmail.com
    server: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-staging
    solvers:
    - http01:
        ingress:
          class: public
```

Don’t forget to add  cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-staging" to ingress yaml file.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-routes
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-staging"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
#change to your domain
    - yourdomain.com
    secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
#change to your domain
  - host: yourdomain.com
    http:
      paths:
        - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: webserver-svc
            port:
              number: 80
```

If possible use the production server address so it is proper with all browsers.

For details follow this [document](https://microk8s.io/docs/addon-cert-manager).